# Как писать сообщения конкретным юзерам firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

[Почитал документацию](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) по firebase и не нашел ничего об отправке сообщений конкретному юзеру...

Сделал по примеру имплементацию , но получается так, что база общая для всех и если кто то из юзеров отправляет сообщение то все подключенные к этой базе его видят.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб можно было отправлять сообщение конкретному юзеру...

Не пойму к чему нужно привязаться и как отправлять в таком случае...

Подскажите как это должно работать?

Comment: Стоит начать с осмотра [механизма авторизации](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-security.html#section-authorization). Это скорее костыль, чем решение, но должно сработать.

Comment: Так ведь устройство получает токен, по токену и отправляйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При регистрации юзера ему выдаётся уникальный ID. Именно по нему и отправляйте сообщение

Comment: Я примерно так и думал, но не пойму как при отправке его указывать... И плюс не пойму как эти сообщения хранятся в самой базе... так как при отправке сообщение сохраняется в виде `json` и как я понимаю все эти `json` складываются как бы в одну таблицу и как только сохраняется сообщение то сразу база синхронизируется со всеми подключеныыми пользователями... То есть если я правильно понимаю при указании этого ид база должна синхронизироваться только с этим конкретным пользователем... Вот тут и не понятно как указывать ид чтоб в итоге синхронизация проходила с этим конкретным устройством

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну, вам надо написать свою логику видимо. Т.е. создавать объект чата, записывать туда ID участующих юзеров и писать сообщения в этот чат. А девайсы юзеров подписать на уведомления из этого конкретного чата

Comment: Юрий хотел у вас уточнить, если знаете... Я так понимаю, что юзеру помимо ид присваевается еще и `firebase tokenId` который храниться на сервере. И система работает так, один юзер пишет сообщение прикладывая ид получателя это сообщение отправляется на сервер, по этому ид сервер находит получателя в базе, берет его токен и по токену отправляет `notification` и в нем передает `topic name` на который получатель автоматически подписывается и таким образом получается чат... Отправитель подписан на `topic` и получатель подписывается на тот же `topic` , верно я понял?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, я лично в чат не лазил, но вроде всё верно - создаётся объект чата с ID на него подписываются юзеры для получения изменений в нём. При отправке сообщения юзер добавляет инфу в этот объект и все подписанные на него получают обновления